# plot conditions in different quadrants

Tags: graphing-functions

i'm studying the plot \dot{y} versus y. 
i defined a function s1 = \dot{y} + k_1 |y|^{2/3} sign(y1)

and another function s2 = sat( |\s1|^{1/2}, a1}

It is true to say , when y, ydot > 0 => S1> 0 and 0 < S2 < a1 ?

could you help me out find the other cases ?

thank you

sincerly